# I'm trying to make a responsive website with a fixed position menu. How do I get the size of the menu div to push the container down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm hoping there is a way to do this without using javascript, but if we must we must. I'm trying to update my portfolio to be responsive, and I've hit my first wall.

I want to have a fixed menu that stays at the top. The next is having the portfolio container lined up to the bottom of the menu, no matter what height it is.

The other thing is, when I put the different sections in my portfolio container, the code that made the background color extend all the way to the left no longer work.

I've tried playing with the z-index and placement for the menu to get around the portfolio background issue, but I wasn't sure if it would make the menu spacing issue harder.

I also tried making a dummy div that was the same size as the menu to push the other divs down. Though it solved some of the issues, it made way more.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Spiderian/wf58yh6r/1/

Here is my code:

```
#menu {
z-index: 100;
min-height: 96px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #62af45;
}
#menu:before {
content:"";
background-color: #62af45;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 200vw;
left: -100vw;
z-index: -1;
}
#portfolio {
overflow-y: auto;
position: relative;
width: 300%
}
#portfolio:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 200vw;
left: -100vw;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fixed menus, you need to manually set the padding-top of the body to push your content down. In your case, your menu is set with a min-height of 96px.

It would be better to set the height so you wouldn't have to worry about it changing on you. This way you can set the padding-top of your body element without problems.

When the screen is too small, you should use a dropdown for the menu. However, you would have to use javascript for that.

See it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

For your headers, the reason why they stick out to the right is because of "margin: 0 auto" for your #wrapper element. All you need to do is remove that line of code. Additionally, your body element has some margin so you should set that to 0.

Here is how they should look:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 106px;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1040px;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu {
    z-index: 100;
    height: 96px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #62af45;
}
```

Fixed menus by nature will cover content. In order to push the content down depending on the size of the menu, you will have to change the menu from being "fixed" to "relative".

You would alter your menu like so:

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear:left;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color: #62af45;
 }
```

Comment: That all makes my website left justified and not responsive. I'm really trying to make it so, no matter how my menu breaks the rest of the content will move down. I'll look into the JS link you provided.

Comment: @horribly_n00bie If the position is fixed there is not a way to achieve what you are looking for. The nature of fixed content is that it follows your view and will cover all other elements.

It explains that here in step 2: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

However, if you changed the menu to position relative, it can work the way you want it, but no longer follows you. I've edited my answer to also include that method.

Comment: It can be done with a fixed menu it just takes javascript. I've started with some jQuery code to measure and return the value of the menu div height on load and whenever the screen size is changed, and I'm trying to get that returned value to adjust the margin size of the first banner.

This is the fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/Spiderian/eLhy5u2k/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:

```css
/* --------------------------------------------------------
Style Sheet: My Portfolio

version: 1.0
last modified: 11.02.2012 by Ian Harper
----------------------------------------------------------*/
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "helvetica", helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 24px;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "helvetica", helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu {
    z-index: 100;
    min-height: 96px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#menu:before {
    content:"";
    background-color: #62af45;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200vw;
    left: -100vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

#portfolio {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 300%
}

#portfolio:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200vw;
    left: -100vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

.menubtn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#hamburgerbtn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 23px;
}

#demoreelbtn {
    
}

#storyboardsbtn {
    
}

#chNbgsbtn {
    
}

#graphicdesignbtn {
    
}

#resumebtn {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.banner {
    height: 96px;
    width: 300%;
    background-color: #62af45;
    position: relative;
}

.banner:before {
    content:"";
    background-color: #62af45;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200vw;
    left: -100vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

.section {
    min-height: 996px;
    width: 300%;
    position: relative;
}

.section:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200vw;
    left: -100vw;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sectionheads {
    padding: 30px;
}

#demoreel {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="menu">
    <div class="menubtn" id="hamburgerbtn">
     <img src="img/Menubtn.png">
    </div>
    <div class="menubtn" id="demoreelbtn">
     <h2>Demo Reel</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menubtn" id="storyboardsbtn">
     <h2>Storyboards</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menubtn" id="chNbgsbtn">
     <h2>Characters/Backgrounds</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menubtn" id="graphicdesignbtn">
     <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="menubtn" id="resumebtn">
     <h2>Resume</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="portfolio">
    <div class="section" id="demoreel">
     <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="sectionheads">Demo Reel</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="storyboard">
     <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="sectionheads">Storyboards</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumb1">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb2">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb3">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb4">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb5">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb6">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb7">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb8">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb9">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb10">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb11">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb12">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb13">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb14">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb15">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb16">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="chNbgs">
     <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="sectionheads">Character and Background Designs</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumb1">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb2">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb3">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb4">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb5">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb6">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb7">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb8">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb9">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb10">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb11">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb12">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb13">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb14">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb15">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb16">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="graphicdesign">
     <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="sectionheads">Graphic Design</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumb1">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb2">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb3">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb4">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb5">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb6">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb7">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb8">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb9">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb10">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb11">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb12">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb13">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb14">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb15">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb16">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That still has the issue of the demo reel banner being covered up by the fixed menu.